# How to close and reconnect to avoid idle-in-transaction timeout using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I wrote a Python app which connects to Postgres DB using SQLAlchemy. The `engine` and `session` are defined in `db.py`

```
engine = create_engine(URL(**settings.DATABASE))
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
```

Most of the db operations are in `service.py` which imports `session` from `db.py`

```
from app.db import engine, session

def get_door_ids():
    result = session.query(ControllerDetail.door_id).distinct().all()
    ids = [c[0] for c in result]
    return ids

def get_last_health_cd(door_id):
    result = session.query(ControllerDetail.door_health_cd).filter(ControllerDetail.door_id == door_id).order_by(ControllerDetail.etl_insert_ts.desc()).first()
    return result[0]
```

Now everything works great, but the problem is I need to run the same thing every couple minutes repeatedly. So I have the following code in my main module:

```
try:
    while True:
        run_task()
        time.sleep(120)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Manual break by user')
```

The DB time out idle connections every minute. So I get error every time the process goes to sleep for more than 1 minute.

```
psycopg2.InternalError: terminating connection due to idle-in-transaction timeout
SSL connection has been closed unexpectedly
```

I wonder if there is a way to close the session and reopen it after `time.sleep(120)` so it won't get timed out. Maybe in the main modole, I import `session` from `db` as a global variable and somehow pass it to methods in `services`. How do I do that? I can't import `session` in `services` from `main` instead of `db` since `main` imports functions from `services`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First and foremost, you should end your transactions timely by committing / rolling back. [Closing](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.close) the session will also implicitly rollback. In case of scoped session [removing](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/contextual.html#sqlalchemy.orm.scoping.scoped_session.remove) will close the session (and remove the session from the registry). All in all ["When do I construct a Session, when do I commit it, and when do I close it?"](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#when-do-i-construct-a-session-when-do-i-commit-it-and-when-do-i-close-it) is a good read at this point.

What might surprise some people is that the `Session` starts a new transaction as soon as you start communicating with the database. It is then your job to end that transaction. Without seeing what `run_task()` actually does it's hard to say which part should be handling the session's lifetime, but it's safe to say that if the task runs every couple minutes, you should not leave a transaction hanging for that long.

Comment: I created `scoped_session` before `run_task()` and closed it after. Now `session` is a parameter of `run_task(session)`. Accordingly all the other functions will have `session` as their parameter as well. Not sure if it is common practice to have `session` as parameter for these query functions, but it works

Comment: When using the thread-local scoped session the lines are a bit more blurred, as one of the selling points is that you don't need to explicitly pass the session around (though nothing wrong with that), and if your tasks (or what have you) are handled by worker threads it is easy to use `scoped_session` to tie the life cycle of session to that of a worker thread. When you say that you used to close the scoped session after `run_task()`, do the loop calling `run_task()` and what it actually does run in the same thread? If not, you created a session and the worker thread another.

Comment: I am not using threading. This is an alert engine, which needs to run every two minutes and polls the database for exceptions. What `run_task` does is just that, queries and sending emails.

Comment: Ah, in that case you don't need a `scoped_session` at all. Just a plain old instance of `Session`, acquired from `sessionmaker()`, will do just fine, and passing it around is a nice pattern; at least it makes testing a lot easier, and promotes reusability.

Answer (score 0):

- Increase the timeout

  `create_engine(URL(**settings.DATABASE), connect_args={'connect_timeout': 10})`
- Create a new session when you get an error
- you can close the connection by `session.close()`

Comment: so the client's timeout setting overrides server's setting? Since the session is created in `db.py` and then gets imported to other module, there is no easy way to create/close the session and have all the methods use the same session as before

Comment: That is the related to your server setting. You can increase up to time you need

Comment: the database is managed by our DBA. And timeout is one of the things he wouldn't change. In order to close and reconnect the `session` in main module, I would have to import it from `db` as a global and pass this to methods in `services`. How do I do that?